# How to convert .model to .tflite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow-lite

I am currently working on a face mask detection project. I do not know machine learning much but here is my problem statement. I have to run my project on Raspberry Pi, so I decided to convert my model to tflite in order to increase the FPS. I trained and created my model in this line 'model.save("mask_detector.model", save_format="h5")' and I used 'res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffeemodel'. However, when I run these lines of code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.contrib import lite

converter = lite.TocoConverter.from_keras_model_file("D:\Face-Mask-Detection-master\mask_detector.model")
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("linear.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

I get an error

```
ImportError: cannot import name ‘lite’.
```

When I run these lines of code

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('mask_detector.model') 
tfmodel = converter.convert() 
open ("model.tflite" , "wb") .write(tfmodel)
```

I get an error

```
File "converty.py", line 14, in <module>
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('mask_detector.model') 
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 747, in from_keras_model_file
    keras_model = _keras.models.load_model(model_file, custom_objects)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 146, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 212, in load_model_from_hdf5
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/model_config.py", line 55, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 89, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 181, in deserialize_keras_object
    config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 166, in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object
    raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name)
ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional
```

How can I convert the .model to .tflite? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TFLite currently supports TensorFlow models only. (The issue is probably due to usinbg `res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffeemodel`). Is there a way get a SavedModel or Keras model in TensorFlow first?